# Como usar qtwebkit-plugins no meu projeto?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qtwebkit

[QtWebkit-plugins](https://github.com/QupZilla/qtwebkit-plugins) é uma biblioteca que prove funcionalidades para o `QWebView`, como [`SpellCheck/Corretor ortografico`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_formsControlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms) e [`Notification Web API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification).

> Leia sobre em:
>
> - [`SpellCheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_formsControlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms)
> - [`Notification Web API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

Eu tentei compilar o código no Windows, mas meu `QWebView` não está funcionando como esperado, em outras palavras o [`SpellCheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_formsControlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms) e [`Notification Web API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) não funcionam, é como se eu não estive-se usando o [QtWebkit-plugins](https://github.com/QupZilla/qtwebkit-plugins). O que pode ser?

Eu li na documentação que para compilar eu deveria executar o seguinte comando:

```
$ qmake
$ make && make install
```

Leia mais em [Repositorio QtWebkit-plugins](https://github.com/QupZilla/qtwebkit-plugins)

Como estou usando o `mingw` eu usei o comando `mingw32-make` ao invés do `make`

- Compilei o `hunspell`
- Copiei `hunspell` compilado para `C:\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\bin` e `C:\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\lib`
- Compilei o `qtwebkit-plugins` usando o comando:

  ```
  $ qmake
  $ mingw32-make && mingw32-make install
  ```
- Foi gerado os arquivos `libqtwebkitpluginsd.a` e `qtwebkitplugins.dll`
- Copiei `libqtwebkitpluginsd.a` para `C:\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\lib`
- Copiei `qtwebkitplugins.dll` para `C:\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\plugins\webkit` e `C:\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\bin`
- Na variáveis de ambiente eu apliquei isto `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1`

Depois eu compilei um projeto simples que usa `QWebView`, então testei o [`SpellCheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_formsControlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms) (`<textarea spellcheck="true"></textarea>`) mas não funcionou.

Eu testei o [`Notification Web API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) e também não funcionou.

Como fazer o [`SpellCheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_formsControlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms) e o [`Notification Web API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) funcionarem?

*Nota:*

Ao rodar um projeto o meu projeto com `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` e usar o [`Notification Web API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
Found metadata in lib C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/webkit/qtwebkitplugins.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qtwebkit.QtWebKit.QtWebKitPlugin",
    "MetaData": {
    },
    "className": "QtWebKitPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 328704
}


loaded library "C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/webkit/qtwebkitplugins.dll"
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/webkit/qtwebkitplugins.dll" 
QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set
```

Parece que a dll é carregada, mas por algum motivo não funciona.

Comment: "As minhas duvidas são, é usar qtwebkit-plugins". Não entendi. Faltou um "possível" ali?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No *Qt 5.2+* não é mais usado os "pacotes" `com.nokia.Qt.*` agora devemos usar `org.qt-project.Qt.*`, portanto para que o `qtwebkit-plugins` funcione é necessário modificar o `qwebkitplatformplugin.h`

Troque isto:

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(QWebKitPlatformPlugin, "com.nokia.Qt.WebKit.PlatformPlugin/1.9");
```

Por isto:

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(QWebKitPlatformPlugin, "org.qt-project.Qt.WebKit.PlatformPlugin/1.9");
```

Se deseja manter a compatibilidade para QT-4.8 e QT-5 também pode-se fazer algo como:

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050200
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(QWebKitPlatformPlugin, "org.qt-project.Qt.WebKit.PlatformPlugin/1.9")
#else
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(QWebKitPlatformPlugin, "com.nokia.Qt.WebKit.PlatformPlugin/1.9")
#endif
QT_END_NAMESPACE
```